# Disable the FocusStyle of the ListViewItem Element in a ListView in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I'am generating a ListView at runtime and populate it continuously. The problem is that I want disable the color change when hovering over an item or selecting it.

Every ListViewItem is not focusable. This way the color change doesn't stay and is only shown when hovering over and item. 
I tried disable this by making my one style but unfortunately it did't work as hoped.

I used this Style

```cs
Setter setter = new Setter()
{
    Property = Control.BackgroundProperty,
    Value = null
};
Setter setter1 = new Setter()
{
    Property = Control.BorderBrushProperty,
    Value = null
};

Trigger trigger = new Trigger()
{
     Property = ListBoxItem.IsSelectedProperty,
     Value = true,
     Setters = { setter, setter1 }
};

Style style = new Style()
{
     Triggers = { trigger }
};
```

I also tried setting the ListView.FocusVisualStyle to null but I also had no results.

Comment: you can set Enabled=false for listview

Comment: I would suggest to use `Transparent` in stead of `null` as a value.

Comment: @irategenius setting enabled = false also disables the scrolling functionality

Comment: @GaurangDave where should I apply the style. I tried ListViewItem.FocusVisualStyle, ListView.ItemContainerStyle and ListView.FoucsVisualStyle. Either of them did not change anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there are 2 options

1) if you dont need to select items : set IsHitTestVisible to false

2) make your own style

```
<!--Default LitsView-->
<Style TargetType="ListView">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource YOUR_BACKGROUND_COLOR}"/>
</Style>

<!--Default LitsViewItem-->
<Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,1"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource YOUR_COLOR}" Opacity="0.3"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter> 
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource YOUR_COLOR}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource YOUR_COLOR}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource YOUR_COLOR}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: just setting IsHitTestVisible=false works for me. Thank you

Comment: @CaptainLama you can use xaml in RunTime just do in your Code `smt.Style = Application.Current.FindResource("YOUR_STYLE_KEY") as Style`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your xaml code...

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I can't use xaml because everything is generated at runtime